# Problemas com LAZY - could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces

Estou com um problema ao tentar carregar um objeto que esta mapeado como LAZY.
Mapeei meu atributo desta forma:

```
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Obra obra;
```

E carrego os dados na hora de abrir a venda assim:

```
   public void carregaItensOs(Venda os) {
    os.setItensVenda(em.createQuery("FROM ItemVenda AS iop WHERE iop.venda=" + os).getResultList());
    os.setObra((Obra) em.createQuery("FROM Obra AS obra WHERE obra.id=" + os.getObra().getId()).getResultList().get(0));
   }
```

Neste caso  a lista de itensVenda carrega certo, o problema é quando tenho que carregar um objeto.

Teria alguma forma de resolver isso ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sem a stack trace completa fica um pouco complicado, mas acredito que o problema esteja em `os.getObra().getId()`.

LazyInitializeException acontece quando um objeto relacionado definido como Lazy não foi carregado em uma consulta. Para isto, você deve adicionar o `FETCH` na sua consulta. Por exemplo:

```
FROM Venda v INNER JOIN FETCH v.obra
```

Provavelmente a venda passada por parâmetro no método `carregaItensOs` não está com a obra carregada e ao chamar `os.getObra().getId()`é lançada a exceção.

Comment: O problema era esse mesmo, porem resolvi de outra forma, salvei o ID da obra em uma coluna separada da venda e carreguei a partir dele.